# How to combine play & pause button into a single button

Tags: android

Here I have 2 buttons for the audio controller, play and pause. How can I combine both buttons into one? I also need the image icon to change as well.

In onCreate, I have initially disabled Pause button.

```
pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Below is the implementation for Play button.

```
public void play(View view){
mediaPlayer.start();
...
pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
playButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Below is the implementation for Pause button.

```
public void pause(View view){
mediaPlayer.pause();
pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
playButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 2 ways :
1. Take a frame layout and put two buttons overlapping each other (by default set visible to play button and hide the pause button) and set visibility according to it like

```
public void play(View view) {
    if(pauseButton.isVisible()) {
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void pause(View view) {
    if(playButton.isVisible()) {
        playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

2. You can take only one button and change it backgroundResource (by default set background resource play) like

```
public void play(View view) {
    Button.setBackgroundResourec(R.drawable.pause);
}

public void pause(View view) {
    Button.setBackgroundResourec(R.drawable.play);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a single button and take a flag as

```
Boolean buttonflag=true;//initially true
```

Suppose true means play and false will mean pause.

```
public void button(View view)
{
  if(buttonflag)//when true play
  {
   mediaPlayer.play();
   buttonflag=false;//set to false so that on next click else will work
  }
  else//when false pause
  {
   mediaPlayer.pause();
   buttonflag=true;//set to true so that on next click if will work
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer m1 = null;

    playAndStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    stopPlaying();
    m1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound1);
    m1.start();
    }
});   

private void stopPlaying() {
     if (mp1 != null) {
        m1.stop();
        m1.release();
        m1 = null;
}
```

This should work for you! Good luck.

Comment: Thank for the quick response. But how would I be able to change the image icon between Play and Pause as well? :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is quite late to answer this question, but i have searched for this question and google shown me this at the top of result, but as i see there is not satisfactory result is available here, So here i am posting my code so that it could help other

```
fabBtnPlayAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!playPause) {
                fabBtnPlayAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
                if (intialStage){
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("URL for audio file.. ");
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                }
                playPause = true;
            } else {
                fabBtnPlayAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_24dp);

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
                playPause = false;
            }

        }
    });
```